# How do you pass arguments to custom zsh functions?

Tags: zsh

How do you pass arguments to custom zsh functions?
For instance:

```sh
function kill_port_proc(port) {
    lsof -i tcp:<port interpolated here>| grep LISTEN | awk '{print $2}'
}
```

I'm seeing so many examples online with ZSH functions, but there barely anything on passing arguments and interpolating them.

Answer (score 58):

When defining a function, you cannot specify required arguments. That's why using both the `function` keyword and parens `()` seems useless to me.

To get the passed arguments, use [positional parameters](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Positional-Parameters).

> **The positional parameters provide access to the command-line arguments of a shell function**, shell script, or the shell itself; [...]
>
> The parameter `n`, where `n` is a number, is the `n`th positional parameter. The parameter `$0` is a special case [...]

About the `$0` positional parameter:

> The name used to invoke the current shell, or as set by the -c command line option upon invocation.
>
> **If the `FUNCTION_ARGZERO` option is set, `$0` is set upon entry to a shell function to the name of the function**, and upon entry to a sourced script to the name of the script, and reset to its previous value when the function or script returns.

Using your example:

```sh
function kill_port_proc {
    lsof -i tcp:"$1" | grep LISTEN | awk '{print $2}'
}
```

Personaly, I like to document the function by, at least, adding the function signature prior to the definition.

Then, I declare local parameters for each arguments and readonly parameters when I want to protect them from unexpected modification.

If the argument is mandatory, I use a special [parameter expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) form:

> `${name?word}`
>
> `${name:?word}`
>
> In the first form, if name is set, or in the second form **if name is both set and non-null**, then substitute its value;
>
> **otherwise, print word and exit from the shell**. Interactive shells instead return to the prompt.
>
> If word is omitted, then a standard message is printed.

How I would write your example:

```sh
# kill_port_proc <port>
function kill_port_proc {
    readonly port=${1:?"The port must be specified."}

    lsof -i tcp:"$port" | grep LISTEN | awk '{print $2}'
}
```

Comment: If leave out "()" when declaring the function every time you source your bash_profile the function will be executed.

Comment: @219CID My answer is specific to Zsh. Use a POSIX compliant syntax to be portable across the shells.

Comment: When will the first form be used?

Comment: Thanks Damien, I used this to make [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/740498/how-to-retain-color-output-with-custom-zsh-function) and I am happy with it :)

Answer (score 11):

```bash
my_function() {
  if [ $# -lt 2 ]
  then
    echo "Usage: $funcstack[1] <first-argument> <second-argument>"
    return
  fi

  echo "First argument: $1"
  echo "Second argument: $2"
}
```

#### Usage

```bash
$ my_function
Usage: my_function <first-argument> <second-argument>

$ my_function foo
Usage: my_function <first-argument> <second-argument>

$ my_function foo bar
First argument: foo
Second argument: bar
```