# What is causing this error in custom zsh function for Apple Script

Tags: macos, applescript, zsh

I am trying to make a zsh function that I can pass an argument to in order to quit a given app using the terminal in the same way that the app quits with the <CMD,Q> shortcut (so not just `pkill`).

I used the example of how to quit apps in macOS terminal from [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/354954/how-can-i-quit-an-app-using-terminal#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20AppleScript%20to%20tell%20the%20application%20to%20quit%3A) and I confirmed that my Zsh function/argument use syntax seems correct from looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127741/how-do-you-pass-arguments-to-custom-zsh-functions#:%7E:text=How%20I%20would%20write%20your%20example%3A) and [this documentation](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion)

```
quitapp() {
  osascript -e 'quit app ${1:?"The application must be specified."}'
}
```

However, I tested it by trying to quit Spotify but when I tried to do so like this:

```
quitapp Spotify
```

I got this error:

```
9:10: syntax error: Expected expression, property or key form, etc. but found unknown token. (-2741)
```

(I tried using both lowercase and uppercase, and tried to enclose Spotify in double quotes or without double quotes, and always the same error).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Pretty much everything after the `quit app` part is not valid AppleScript.  `osascript` is expecting a string containing valid AppleScript, but you are mixing in shell stuff - is that supposed to be a ternary statement?

Comment: I'm curious to see what happens when you do `echo 'quit app ${1:?"The application must be specified."}'`, does it output a valid AppleScript statement?

Comment: @red_menace I meant for that to be executed in the shell you're right. It was meant to be the left expression if that variable exists, and the right expression otherwise.

Comment: @user3579815 no that doesn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

While struggling some more I stumbled upon [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/354954/how-can-i-quit-an-app-using-terminal#:%7E:text=I%20added%20this%20to%20my%20.zshrc%20to%20quit%20an%20app%20using%20Matteo%27s%20answer) and I recognize that my mistake was thinking that string would be evaluated as shell code before being passed.

But I can just solve my question with (credit to the SO answer I linked to):

```
qapp() {
    osascript -e "quit app \"$1\""
}
```